# How to loop on multiple databases and tables

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have a SQL Server instance which contains multiple databases. I have 2 tables which exist in all databases on the server:

1. Refresh Log
2. Detailed refresh log.

I want to union all the tables across all databases on the server so the final result will be 2 tables which are the union refresh log and detailed refresh log.

I need help to write the function which runs across all databases.

Comment: Where, exactly, are you stuck here? There are plenty of examples (some good, some bad) that demonstrate how to run a query against multiple databases, normally with dynamic SQL in a loop or a full batch; what about those didn't you understand? Are the tables dynamic too? You need to give a lot more detail on exactly what your task is, where in that task you've got to and why you aren't able to progress past that.

Comment: You don't want a function for this. You can either just write out the query manually or if you need it to adjust for new databases then you will need some dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also a little uncertain as to what you're hoping for, for example if you need the resulting output to be in two permanent tables or if you just need the result when queried.  Of course once you build your SELECT you can return it to the caller or put it into a table, so I'll leave that up to you.

If your databases are unchanging, then of course you can just write your query and maybe put it into a VIEW for convenience:

```
SELECT columns from database1.dbo.RefreshLog
UNION ALL
SELECT columns from database2.dbo.RefreshLog
...
```

and so on

But if you're saying that your databases are themselves dynamic, in other words that databases may be created or dropped over the lifetime of your project, then you could consider using the "undocumented" procedure *sp_msforeachdb* to build up a list of databases, and then use THAT list to build your UNION query.  Here's a quick script that captures the names of all databases that include a specific table ("Products" in the example):

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#DatabaseNames') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #DatabaseNames

CREATE TABLE #DatabaseNames (DatabaseName SYSNAME)

execute sp_msforeachdb @command1=
N'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE Name = ''Products'')
     INSERT #DatabaseNames VALUES(N''Database [?]'')'

SELECT * FROM #DatabaseNames
```

Comment: This approach will work but the sp_msforeachdb has some issues. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/